# How to create a shortcut to a file on Fileshare and hide the path from user

Tags: powershell, file-sharing, file-permissions, batch-file, shortcut

we are sharing a certain powershell script to our remote users; the powershell script wuill be hosted on the file share and the link(shortcut) to the bat file(which executed the powershell script) will be propagated on the desktops of the users.The problem is when they right click and see the properties of the shortcut, they can read the path and then they can read the bat file which shows the location of the script; how can everything be hidden from the remote users? We dont want them to find the path and access the bat or powershell scripts.If we take away the read access to the script can they execute it via shortcut->bat file? Please let me know your thoughts and alternate solutions if possible.

Please do let me know if any questions or clarifications required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking to do is impossible. If you can't read it, then you can't execute it. Notice that Windows permissions are "Read" and "Read & Execute". You can not separate Read and Execute.

Maybe if you explained why you think it's such a bad thing to be able to read the batch file or the PowerShell script we might be able to propose an alternative.

Comment: Mainly security reasons since some of those remote users being inmates and we dont have much control of our remote admin's workstations too since they share them.

Comment: Need more detail. Why is it a problem if they see the contents of the files? What do they do?